# Can someone please explain this regex filtering of an array

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm filtering an array, and found a regex on here.
I'm trying to understand this:

```
filterArray.filter(/./.test.bind(new RegExp(key, 'g')))
```

But I don't understand how the array tests it value against the regex or why you have to start with /./ instead of just writing the regex. And how does bind work in this case?

EDIT: Key is just a string that I want to match, "hi" or "dog" or "anything really".

Comment: If you give us variable `key` then yes.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: Somebody is being way too clever. Creating a dummy RegExp (/./) just to get access to the `test` function is just showing off.

Comment: @RaymondChen, any other way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: @Dogbert `RegExp.prototype.test.bind(new RegExp(key, "g"))`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `.bind()` method will return a function with whatever you passed as the first argument bound as the value of `this`.

Since you're calling `.bind()` from `.test()`, you're getting the `.test()` method with the `this` bound to `new RegExp(key, 'g')`.

The `/./` is irrelevant here. It's just short way of getting to the `RegExp.prototype.test` method.

The result is that you'll effectively be doing:

```
var regexp = new RegExp(key, 'g');

filterArray.filter(function(val) {
    return regexp.test(val);
});
```

---

You should note that this is a little bit dangerous, because a regex object with the `g` modifier is stateful. This means it always starts a new search where the previous one left off.

Given this filtering scenario, the `g` doesn't seem at all necessary, and could really only cause problems.

Here's an example of the danger of using the `g` here:

```
var re = /./.test.bind(new RegExp("foo", 'g'));
var str = "foobar";

console.log(re(str));  // true
console.log(re(str));  // false
```

So calling the same regex on the same string produces two different results. If we called it again, it would be `true` once again.

---

So given the use as a `.filter()` callback, let's say `key` is `"foo"`, then lets say one `val`  is `"foobar"`. It will be allowed through the filter.

But let's say the very next `val` is `"foobaz"`. The search will resume on the fourth character instead of starting from the first, so the `"foo"` will not be found.

---

Here's concrete example that shows the issue in action:

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/s9PzL/

```
var filterArray = [
    "foobar",
    "foobaz",
    "foobuz",
    "foobix"
];

var result = filterArray.filter(/./.test.bind(new RegExp("foo", 'g')));
```

All the strings have `"foo"`, so they should all get through. But the result shows that doesn't happen.

```
document.body.textContent = result.join(", "); // foobar, foobuz
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about making it global. And the result of what I'd effectively am doing helped.

Comment: When you say the search resumes on the 4th char, you mean the 4th char of the next element in the array, right?

Comment: @kjelelokk: Correct. The regexp object remembers that the last match ended at index `2`, so if the same regexp object is used again to do another search, it'll start at index `3`. This is the case even if it is searching a different string, which is the case here. When it doesn't find a match, it resets itself. And FYI, you can see what the index is using the `.lastIndex` of the regexp object. You can also reset it to `0` manually. Of course that's not possible if you're binding it as `this` without holding a reference to it.

Comment: Thanks @CrazyTrain, CRUCIAL comment about the statefulness of the global tag in regexes, I haven't seen that documentation anywhere else but it can lead to strange side-effects in the context of filtering.

Comment: Thanks for this lovely answer dude. I did not know `RegExp.prototype.test`.

Answer (score 6):

I think the reason this is done this way is because you want to execute the test method on each item in the array. Just passing the test method to filter will (presumably) mess up the binding of the method.

That's why in your example:

```
/./
```

Generates an empty regex

```
/./.test
```

is the test method on that regex

```
/./.test.bind(new Regex(..))
```

binds that method to the requested method, and returns a new method that executes `test` where `this` is your supplied regex based on `key`.

It seems that it could have been written a lot more clear:

```
RegExp.prototype.test.bind(new RegExp(key, 'g'))
```

Comment: I can only guess that the author is too clever to type 13 more chars.